# Why can't Android find class in project on build path?

Tags: android, eclipse, package, project

I'm building an Android app and I'd like to use a class from a package in another Eclipse project (a plain Java, non-Android one, if that matters).  I right-click on the Android project, choose properties | Java build path | Projects and check the one with the class I want.  I then add an import statement, which Eclipse appears to accept (i.e. error icons indicating that it doesn't recognize the class disappear).  Here's the code for the main activity:

```
package com.MeadowEast.tmptest;

import learn.Card; // the class I want
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView t  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Card c = new Card("abc","def","ghi"); // using the class
        t.setText(c.getHanzi());
    }
}
```

Using exactly the same approach with a non-Android Java project works fine.  But when I attempt to run the above in an emulator it dies and the error is `Could not find class 'learn.Card'`.

I had a similar problem once with a JAR file and learned that there were two necessary steps (the second one being to put a copy of the JAR in the libs folder).  Is a second step necessary here too?  Or is something else the matter?

Comment: Yes, if it is jar, you should put into libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to manage this.

1. Compile and include a jar in libs directory
2. Compile and include using some kind of dependency management (a la Maven).
3. Eclipse allows for libraries to depend on other (uncompiled) libraries in the project workspace
4. Android Studio allows for a module to depend on another (uncompiled) module

Note: Options 3 and 4 are very similar to a light weight version of option 2.

Also note, for a small project, 2 is likely to be overkill an probably introduces unwanted additional compile time.

Personally, I would prefer option 1 for projects where the library doesn't change of often and options 3/4 for projects where the library depended on was changing frequently.

The benefit of 1 is that you don't get surprised when the library changes (changes in api, - you have to make a concious effort to update to the latest). The benefit of 3/4 is that if you are updating the library to work with the project you don't have to constantly recompile and import jars.

Answer (score 0):

There are different answers to this, depending on which IDE you are using.

If you are using Eclipse/ADT, you should be able, simply, to drop the jar into a top level directory named "libs".  Be sure to get the name *exactly* right.

Even after you do this, Eclipse may need "jiggling" to get it to notice the new file.  Unless you see an entry for "Android Private Libraries", which contains your library, it hasn't noticed.  Try re-building, re-importing, refreshing and so on.  Feh.

If you are using Intellij/Studio (and thus Gradle), you need to add a line to the Gradle build file like this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

It goes in the `dependencies` clause of the `build.gradle` file in the `app` folder.

This time the jar file itself goes into the directory `app/libs`

After you do that "jiggle" Studio.  "Sync", "Clear cache and restart". All the usual tricks.  You know you've succeeded when your library turns up in the "Project" pane, under the "External Libraries" tab

Answer (score -1):

If you use source code, Please put them in your project.

If you use jar, you should put into libs folder. Because, when you run your app in device, all

your code must in your apk (excepts framework.jar), otherwise it can't find your code. If you

put your jar in libs folder, the eclipse(exactly the apkbuilder) will package them into apk

file.

Comment: This confuses me for two reasons.  First, if reusing code means having multiple copies of it, then I have a maintenance nightmare.  If I want to change the reused code in any way, I'll have to edit each copy separately.  Second, if copying the code is necessary, what's the point of the adding the project to the build path?

Comment: @user1236910,if you do not want keep two copies, you can use jar.  you  could add a pre-build(which make your source code to jar) to this android project and move the jar to libs

Comment: This is not a reasonable solution. I agree with @user1236910 . This kind of practice quickly results in a dependency/versioning nightmare with impossible to maintain (lack of) code reuse.